# Mystical oriental kitten

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

In this article 
https://aeon.co/ideas/tidying-up-is-not-joyful-but-another-misuse-of-eastern-ideas

what does this sentence mean? 
"Which, to be clear, they are. Poor old Confucius features in these memes as a mystical oriental kitten, telling us all to hang in there!

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/content/images/frontcover/KEMFmlv1uKcC?fife=w200-h300  This is a common poster theme. "Hang in there" is an idiom that means "Don't give up."

Comment: I need an explanation for the whole sentence please

Comment: The sentence, aside from the idiom, is straightfoward English.  If you understood the paragraph, you should be able to understand the final sentences.  People today cite Confucius in support of "mini-homilies" - very short sermons - exhorting us to make sound choices, like tidying up or persevering against adversity ("Hang in there.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully checking the context of the paragraph-

"*Which, to be clear, they are."* refers to the statement "*we might believe them to be yet more dull mini-homilies*". 
"they" and "them" refer to the list of things in the paragraph that are supposed to have been said by Confucius.

"*Poor old Confucius features in these memes as a mystical oriental kitten, telling us all to hang in there!"* refers to a specific inspirational poster that portrays a dangling cat and the phrase "Hang in there"

The author is complaining about the misuse of the East Asian philosophies in popular culture and the kitten poster is used as an example.

Comment: Is the "Hang in There" kitten Asian? I had no idea. That poster dates back to the 1970s at least.